# New wiki-question : online publications sorted by the names

Tags: discussion, feature-request

After following the link provided by **@theUg** in his question [Are the Russian “рыжий” and French “rouge” (red) related? / Как связаны русское «рыжий» и французское «rouge»?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/q/1857/1329) , I concluded that it would be a nice idea to create one more wiki-question (similar to  [Resources for learning Russian](https://russian.stackexchange.com/q/833/1329)), where participants could share online resources with links to articles written by Russian linguists (sorted by name). Also it could be possible to share links to lectures, videos, ?biography? etc.

Proposed structure for each **answer**:

### Name of linguist/researcher

- **Short biography/profile** (and/or link to full one) - about 5 lines...
- **Links to articles** list (chronological order, with descriptions) - editable
- **Links to videolectures** list - editable

Why do I think it would be useful? Well, first of all, people interested in a particular language once come to a point when they wish to read professional articles about this language. Secondly, it will increase the number of native speakers on this site. And last, it will be useful for members of **Russian language and usage** who wish to broaden their horizon in Russian linguistic and learn something new (like me for example).

So, my question is: **does anybody except me need it?**

Any suggestions and/or corrections of the idea will be welcome.

Comment: Well, I don't feel particularly against this, but... who's going to take care of it? I mean, at first everybody might help but in the long run I see it just getting abandoned. :P We can try to set it on Meta though, if there is enough interest here.

Comment: @Alenanno, I don’t think setting it on Meta would help for practical reasons: most people do not venture here, and those that do, do not go very often (hell, I had missed a week here). Semantically, however, it could be a proper place to have it, pending debate.

Comment: @theUg The fact is that on the Main site it would be off topic: we treat the Russian Language and Usage, not this. And maybe even on Meta, but on Meta I'd let it be.